# Not found page when refresh the page in Vite project deployed

Tags: reactjs, vite

I can navigate to all my pages after deploy my project on Vite using React, but when I refresh the page on certain path or write the path directly on the browser I got 404 page not found.

**Here's my router:**

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/products/:id" component={ProductView}></Route>
    <Route path="/home" component={Home}></Route>
    <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}></Route>
    <Route path="/not-found" component={NotFound}></Route>
    <Redirect path="/" exact to="/home" />
    <Redirect path="" exact to="/home" />
</Switch>
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react({
    include: "**/*.jsx",
  })]
})
```

**I'm using**

```
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
```

I tried with react-router 6, adding a 200.html page, adding wildcards to the routers but none of those works at the moment. Any light in the dark? This only happens on project deployed on my server either in Vite or my LocalServer.

When I run `yarn run dev` everything works perfect even refreshing the page or writing the url on the browser.

**UPDATE 23/2023**

Maybe someone is dealing with this, specifically with VITE app. What @adsy says it's correct this require to setup wildcard routes. This happens because react router project just live there, and the server needs to be configure to work properly with react router or any other SPA. VITE doesn't have any special input to configure this specific, So what you have to do it's create a dockerfile that allows you to wrap your application instead of working with VITE default server configuration.

**Here's an example of DockerFile in VITE:**

```
FROM node:14-alpine AS builder

ARG YOUR_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES
ARG YOUR_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES

# Add a work directory
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN yarn install

COPY . /app/

RUN yarn build

FROM nginx:alpine

# Set working directory to nginx asset directory
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

# Remove default nginx static assets
RUN rm -rf ./*

COPY --from=builder /app/dist .

COPY .nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And that's the solution for this specific issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nav links work but manually typing url does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73664563/nav-links-work-but-manually-typing-url-does-not-work)

Comment: Above is an answer I posted on another Q, but your issue is the same. You need to setup wildcard routes _serverside_ to serve the index.html

Comment: Part of it @adsy Thanks! I need to address my question to how to setup a wildcard route on railway app.

Comment: How about a local development run? Any suggestions how to deal with this issue?

Comment: getting error with this on build "ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref moby::qu00a4iupma6r8gen6lpdp1jn: "/.nginx/nginx.conf": not found:", any idea? @napstercake

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue deploying a react app built with vite. I solved it by editing the .htaccess to redirect all urls (except statics) to index.html deals with rendering the correct page based on the route.

A snippet of the .htaccess configuration below:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L,QSA]
```

This approach was based on the following StackOverflow question: [How to redirect all pages only to index.html using htaccess file and not redirect the image files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709500/how-to-redirect-all-pages-only-to-index-html-using-htaccess-file-and-not-redirec)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? what is that .htaccess file? and where should it be in the project folder?

Comment: It depends on your deployment. I was deploying on a hosting provider that had its own custom setup, the .htaccess was on a www folder. And I was using an Nginx server.

Answer (score 1):

I was with the same problem in a project deployed in Netlify, and i solved with those simple steps bellow.

1 - Make sure to create a public/_redirects file with the following rewrite rules:

```js
/*  /index.html  200
```

Comment: your answer looks incomplete. Can you check it please?